# Synchronize post and get http

Tags: api, rest, http, synchronization

This might be a stupid question but I really can't figure it out. Let's say I have a server exposing a REST API, and an app consuming that API, let's say it's a mobile app. The app wants to post something on the server, a new user for instance, and then it wants to get all the users back to display that the new user is added. This will work in general but sometimes the list won't contain the new user because we are not guaranteed that the post will happen before the get. So my question is how can we enforce that the post will be done before the get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send the `GET` until the response from the `POST` comes back.